# Collections wont serialise with protobuf-net?

Tags: protobuf-net

I'm evaluating Protobuf-net to speed up a WCF project and so far it's looking promising but I've got a problem with lists (and dictionaries) coming out null on the client side.

**EDIT**
*This question turned out to be wrong the issue is with empty collections not anything to do with the contents. I'm updating it so anyone stumbling across it might get some help.*
**EDIT**

This is the (simplified) code

```
    [ProtoContract]
    public class TestObject
    {
        [ProtoMember(1)]
        public List<int> Values { get; set; }
    }

    public Test()
    {

        TestObject bob = new TestObject() { Values = new List<int>() };
        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            Serializer.Serialize<TestObject>(stream, bob);

            stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

            TestObject copy = Serializer.Deserialize<TestObject>(stream);

            // Fail!
            Debug.Assert(copy.Values != null);
        }
    }
```

When I look at Values in the copy it is null not an empty List object.

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong? I'm using protobuf-net full 2.0.0.668

Thanks,
Mark

Comment: I'm going to have to look into this later; working at the moment

Comment: Thanks very much, actually the struct thing might be a red-herring, another collection that isn't working is a dictionary of class objects. I'm just looking for a pattern.

Comment: I've found the problem. It's nothing to do with structs and classes. If the collection is empty the you get null on the deserialised object instead of an initialised but empty collection. This happens even on a very simple test harness.

Comment: I'm a bit confused what object we are talking about if the collection is empty; would love to see a small but complete example.

Comment: I'm about to update the Question and answer it. Basically it's identical to issue 58 and 131 on the google-code project. Empty collections deserialise as null. It seems this is the way it has to be but it will cause us a big headache if we migrate. Maybe we could add an attribute to always create an empty collection and never null?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this is the behaviour of protobuf because the underlying standard has no distinction between a null list and an empty list.

Look at issues [58](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/issues/detail?id=58) and [131](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/issues/detail?id=131&q=empty%20null) on the project site.

For anyone migrating from DataContract especially with WCF this will be quite a surprise.

Possible workarounds include initialising inline, or in the constructor or change your code to accept null or patch it up afterwards like this.

```
    [ProtoAfterDeserialization]
    public void Fix()
    {
        Values = Values ?? new List<int>(0);
    }
```